# Acer Aspire E1-140 Keyboard Arrow keys(Up,Down,Right) Not working

Tags: keyboard, acer, aspire

Acer Aspire E1-140 Intel Celeron quad core processor Notebook Arrow keys(UP,DOWN,RIGHT) not working. I have tested ubuntu-14.04,Lubuntu-14.04 and Linux Mint 17 theses distro but result was same.Help me?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having hte same problem here http://askubuntu.com/questions/583304/arrow-keys-cause-touchpad-indicator-to-show and getting no answers.

Comment: Reconfigure your keyboard setting with your vendor name.